# How to list all explicitly called classes and methods in C# programs?

Tags: c#, reflection

I wrote a C# DLL that calls many third-party APIs.
Now I would like to summarize which third-party API classes and methods I have called in total.
For example, I just need to output the qualified name of the class and method I explicitly call to the console(excluding sub-calls that I didn't write in my xxx.cs file).

Comment: Remove the reference to the dll and try to build. The error list will include every called method.